# in javascript how to send request some url at a partcular time(e.g daily 5 pm)

Tags: javascript

in javascript how to send request some url at a partcular time(e.g daily 5 pm).........

very day @5pm i have to send some request (url)e.g sending emails how to do in java script

Comment: Assuming you are running JavaScript on your server: add a cron job to execute the script. If you are running your JavaScript somewhere else, you might want to add more detail to your question :)

Comment: Javascript is mainly a client language seems that there is something wrong on your idea, maybe I didn't get it. Could you give us more details?

Comment: Agreed - you should describe your application. @Claudio Javascript is definitely used as a server-side language, but there are many different frameworks so we don't know how to answer.

Comment: While JS is *mainly* used client side in webpages, doing something at a particular *time* (as opposed to every *x* seconds/minutes) in a webpage is extremely unusual. Step back, tell us what you are trying to achieve (and why you are trying to do it in a webpage if that is what you are trying to do). If you are trying to make an HTTP request to a particular URL to cause a server side process to send email at a certain time … then you probably have an overcomplicated system and should take the webserver and everything HTTP out of the equation.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, I've said MAINLY :-) and I think I'm not wrong if I said that is 99.9% used on client side, that counts as MAINLY. Thanks for make it more clear anyway.

Comment: @Claudio oh yes, that's true; I was mostly thinking that this really only makes sense on the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to hazard an answer anyway:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //payload here
}, 3600000*24); //one day. Launch at 5pm :)
```

This is quite simple and ugly, you probably want to add more detail to the condition (minutes, etc)

Comment: With the right timing this might skip the whole hour completely, by ticking in just before 17:00 and then due to inaccuracies in the timing system in the OS tick in just after 18:00, or it might end up ticking twice, just after 17:00 and just before 18:00.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do it this way. If you have access to the server take a look at [scheduled tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) (for windows) or [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (for linux).

If you absolutely have no other alternatives the only way to accomplish this would be to create a loop with `setInterval` and check the current time in every iteration. But I just cringed writing that.

Comment: `setInterval` not `setTimeout`

Comment: my main requirement is sending mails daily exactly @ 5pm ....@5 i it should trigger or call the mail sending function......

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
var now = new Date();
// 17 o'clock today
var target = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 17);

setTimeout(function(){
    // do stuff  
}, target.getTime() - now.getTime());
```

But regarding your question this is not a convenient solution. It means that you have to have the JS code running the whole day (with my example you even have to reload the code every day). A cron job is really a much more appropriate solution. There are also [free cron job services on the internet](http://www.setcronjob.com/).